# PowerShell doesn't recognize provided parameter

Tags: rest, powershell, content-type

Operating System - **Windows 10**

Powershell version - **5.1.15063.1088**

I'm using *Windows PowerShell ISE* (if that makes any sense). When running simple HTTP Post function

```
Function MyBeautifulFunction {

  $myCredentials = Get-Credential

  $body = @{
          "query"="SELECT [System.Wheel],[System.SparkPlug],[System.EngineOil],[System.Headlight],[System.RadioButton] FROM JunkYard WHERE [System.Brand] = 'Ford' AND [System.Model] = 'GT' AND [System.Title] CONTAINS 'Rebuild'"
  } | ConvertTo-Json

  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://example.com//ford/parts/fuelpump/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.0' `
    -Method Post `
    -Credential $myCredentials `
    -Body $body `
    -ContentType 'application/json' 

}

MyBeautifulFunction
```

<sup>Editor's note: The `Invoke-RestMethod` call was originally spread across 2 lines without line continuation, which part of [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50843879/45375) below discusses.</sup>

I'm getting following error message in PowerShell ISE console window:

```
"message":"The request indicated a Content-Type of \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" for method type \"POST\" which is not supported. Valid 
content types for this method are: application/json, application/json-patch+json.
```

It's clearly visible that I'm passing `'application/json'` in the parameter, but for some reason PowerShell still complains. Has anyone faced this error before? Should I report to Microsoft with it? Thanks for the advice...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things...

First, I call REST services all the time with a content type of application/json, and I don't have any problems. For example, the following works fine for me:

```
$url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
$response_from_webservice = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -ContentType 'application/json' -Method 'Get'
```

jsonplaceholder... is a public service, available for testing. Feel free to run the snippet on your machine in-case you need a sanity check.

Second, this sample code you sent had this `Accept` parameter:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://example.com//ford/parts/fuelpump/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.0' -Method Post -Credential $myCredentials 
-Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Accept 'application/json'
```

I don't believe I've seen that before. I am also running Windows 10 with Powershell v5.1.15063.1088. I've checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6). I checked out the commandlet's parameters. I didn't find it.

[image]

I share this to explain, I can't recreate your scenario with that call signature.

If you want to add an `accept` entry to the HTTP header, you'd have to do that directly:

```
$h = new-object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[[string],[string]]'
$h.add('accept', 'application/json')
$r = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri '...' -ContentType 'application/json' -Method 'Post' -Headers $h
```

Third, it sort of looks like you're not specifying the content type in your snippet. The snippet has the `Invoke-RestMethod` on a seperate line from the body and contenttype parameters. Just to be clear, it's not wrapping. It looks like there is a line break there. That means that the second line `-Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Accept 'application/json'` is unassociated with the call that precedes it; the following is a copy and paste from your post:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://example.com//ford/parts/fuelpump/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.0' -Method Post -Credential $myCredentials 
-Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -Accept 'application/json'
```

If you want to put the parameters on a separate line, just use a backtick.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://example.com//ford/parts/fuelpump/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.0' `
-Method Post `
-Credential $myCredentials `
-Body $body `
-ContentType `
'application/json'
```

Now, if you don't specify the ContentType (as I'm suggesting) it will default to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" on a post. According to Microsoft:

> -ContentType
>
> Specifies the content type of the web request.
>
> If this parameter is omitted and the request method is POST,
>   Invoke-RestMethod sets the content type to
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Otherwise, the content type is not
>   specified in the call.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've added everything in one line - still doesn't work. I removed Accept (even though it's mandatory to pass this as Post request for my endpoint) parameter - doesn't work. Added Content-Type as value of the $headers variable - doesn't work. Every time I see same error message: The request indicated a Content-Type of \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" for method type \"POST\" which is not supported. Valid 
content types for this method are: application/json, application/json-patch+json."

Comment: So, let's talk a little more about that `Accept` entry in the header. `Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't ship with a parameter to specify what the response format should look like. If you want to add entry, you need to do it manually. I've updated my answer with an example of how to add it. If your service requires that header entry and your not supplying it, it might be a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass headers in to the headers argument

```
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json",
    "Accept" = "application/json"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://example.com/123' -Method Post -Body $body -Headers $headers
```

See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod

Comment: Thanks! On the documentation page it's clearly says that Invoke-RestMethod method accepts ContentType as parameter. So if the request method is Post, ContentType is always set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Beautiful implementation of the parameter.

Comment: This is a great way to pass header data, but you can pass ContentType as a parameter as well - just an FYI.

Comment: @Kevin Smith By the way I believe it should be $headers = @{
"Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

with quotes around Content-Type, otherwise PoweShell complains on the dash character between Content and Type words